# How to go to a highlighted function in radare2?

Tags: radare2

In radare2, after hitting "v", I can scroll through the code, and also selection function calls with the cursor. I'm curious how I can jump to the definition of a function, as in "step into" a function call that's highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

In visual mode, you can use `s` to step into a function, or `S` to step over a function.